# Can Analog library be used to create multiple log files?

Tags: php, logging, logfiles, php-analog-package

I'm looking for a decent, easy to use logging helper class-set/framework.

I discovered [Analog](https://github.com/jbroadway/analog) and find it to be exactly what I need, despite the fact that it seems to be usable for one logfile at a time only.

Am I wrong ?!

Do you know some similar (in size/functionality) project that allows multiple logs to be written? An Analog-Branch maybe? I had a look at log4php, KLogger and Monolog already.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from the source code at

- https://github.com/jbroadway/analog/blob/master/examples/file.php and
- https://github.com/jbroadway/analog/blob/master/examples/multi.php and
- https://github.com/jbroadway/analog/blob/master/lib/Analog/Handler/Multi.php

you should be able to use several file handlers at the same time. Try something along the lines of this:

```
Analog::handler(Analog\Handler\Multi::init(array(
    Analog::ERROR   => Analog\Handler\File::init('/path/to/logs/errors.log'),
    Analog::WARNING => Analog\Handler\File::init('/path/to/logs/warnings.log'),
    Analog::DEBUG   => Analog\Handler\File::init('/path/to/logs/debug.log')
)));
```

---

If you cannot make it work with `Analog\Handler\Multi`, you can still write your own [Composite](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite) Logger, adapting the Analog File Handler. To do that, first create an Interface defining how you want to use Loggers in your application:

```
interface Logger
{
    const ERROR = 'error';
    const WARNING = 'warning';
    const DEBUG = 'debug';

    public function log($message, $level);
}
```

Then create the Adapter for Analog so that it satisfies the Interface:

```
class AnalogAdapter implements Logger
{
    private $adaptee;

    public function __construct(Analog $analog)
    {
        $this->adaptee = $analog;
    }

    public function log($message, $level)
    {
        $adaptee = $this->adaptee;
        $adaptee::log($message, $adaptee::$level);
    }
}
```

Finally, write the Composite Logger:

```
class CompositeLogger implements Logger
{
    private $loggers = array;

    public function registerLogger(Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->loggers[] = $logger;
    }

    public function log($message, $level)
    {
        foreach ($this->loggers as $logger)
        {
            $logger->log($message, $level);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you create your Analog file handlers and register them with the Composite:

```
$logger = new CompositeLogger;
$logger->registerLogger(
    new AnalogAdapter(
        Analog\Handler\File::init('/path/to/logs/errors.log')
    )
);

// … add more Loggers in the same way

$logger->log('This is a warning', Logger::WARNING);
```

The warning will then get written to all the registered Loggers.

Comment: Whoo! Thanks for that detailed answer, i'll have closer look on that for sure. But what i realize by having a quick glance is, that is does not allow to write mulitple logfiles eiter.. o) I meant to write different log files, with different content. I'd like to have a "error.log" and a "audit.log" file, logging different things. It seems to me, i can't do this with that static implementation of Analog.

Comment: @RobertG. I am afraid, I don't know Analog well enough to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does work great. And you can create different log functions for different log types.

EG. This will email errors. But write warnings to a log.

```
Analog::handler(Analog\Handler\Multi::init(array(
    Analog::ERROR   => Analog\Handler\Buffer::init (
    Analog\Handler\Mail::init (
        'you@example.com',
        'Log messages',
        'noreply@example.com'
    )
)
    ,Analog::WARNING => Analog\Handler\File::init(__DIR__.'/log/warning.log')
    //Analog::DEBUG   => Analog\Handler\File::init('/path/to/logs/debug.log')
)));
```